# My Job Applications are not shown unless I open them by the notification email

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow-jobs

If I try to view my job applications from the desktop web interface (Devevolper Jobs > inbox icon > Applications), it shows nothing:

`Bummer. There isn't anything to show here right now.`
The url it opens is https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages#!/inbox/applications and of course I'm signed in in the site.

But if I open the link in the email I received after applying to a job opportunity, I can then see all my applications. In that case the url is slightly different:
https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/messages?userId=117963/#!/sent/applications
As you can see it includes the `userId` in query string that is not included in the first url.
This happens in both Chrome and Firefox (both latest) on Linux. Not tried anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Look under the `Sent/Applications` folder instead. `Inbox/Applications` is intended for employers.

Comment: Ooops! Shame on me... Sorry